# Problems with testing a function that "returns" "Unit" in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockito

I try to test a function that "return" "**Unit**", but when I try to mock the "response", the test failed because the test result was null. I'm using **Mockito**

The test is the next:

```
@Test
    fun myFunctionToTest_Success() = runBlocking {
        Mockito.`when`(repository.myFunctionToTest(mock(MyRequest::class.java)))
            .thenReturn(ApiResultHandle.Success(Unit))

        val result = repository.myFunctionToTest(mock(MyRequest::class.java))

        Truth.assertThat(result).isEqualTo(ApiResultHandle.Success(Unit))
    }
```

The function that i testing is:

```
suspend fun myFunctionToTest(request: MyRequest): ApiResultHandle<Unit> =
        remoteDataSource.someFunctionThatConsumeService(request)
```

I have this error:

```
expected: Success(value=kotlin.Unit)
but was : null
expected: Success(value=kotlin.Unit)
but was : null
```

Sorry I'm not expert in test

Comment: Why do you stub the thing that you are testing? That doesn't look right. Your SUT (system under test) shouldn't be mocked itself, its external dependencies should be

Comment: In other words: Your test is not testing anything. It's testing nothing (except that Mockito itself works and that it can stub method calls). The line `remoteDataSource.someFunctionThatConsumeService` is never executed in your test

Answer (score 0):

Mockito will be expecting the arguments sent to to the mocked method invocation to match, ie being equal. You could mock with

```
Mockito.`when`(repository.myFunctionToTest(any()))
        .thenReturn(ApiResultHandle.Success(Unit))
```

instead. I would also recommend using [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) to mitigate some of the issues with Mockito and Kotlin. That will also allow you to write

```
whenever(repository.myFunctionToTest(any()))
    .thenReturn(ApiResultHandle.Success(Unit))
```

Good luck with your testing!

Comment: I'd also recommend to consider about using MockK (https://mockk.io). Unlike mockito-kotlin that is a bridge between mockito and Kotlin, MockK is pure Kotlin framework. It also supports coroutines out of the box

Comment: Thansk you, that worked for me, and thanks for the suggestion, we'll try to migrate to mockito-kotlin

Comment: @JCisneros95 As per the comment below the question you should *not* be mocking the thing you're trying to test. If that's what you're doing, your test is worthless (for actually testing if your code works)

Comment: It is customary to "accept" the answer if it helped and you are happy with it. It will credit some rep to the user that answered...